# How to hide messages of two different format in one image and retrieve in same format after decoding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography

How can I hide messages with two different format e.g. `int` and `string` in an image at the same time and decrypt the messages in same format?

```
                                                             
from stegano import lsb
a = 12345678
b = 'sdghgnh'
c = (a, b)
secret = lsb.hide("images/2.png",str(c))
secret = secret.save("new.png")
clear_message = lsb.reveal(secret)
print(clear_message)
```

In the above code: `a` is an integer and `b` is a string data type. I need to hide them in `2.png` image file and return a stego image called `new.png`. How can I decode the messages from the image in same format?

I got the  following errors while decoding:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2770, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rashik/Desktop/fyp/abc.py", line 7, in <module>
    clear_message = lsb.reveal(secret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/stegano/lsb/lsb.py", line 103, in reveal
    img = tools.open_image(input_image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/stegano/tools.py", line 120, in open_image
    return Image.open(fname_or_instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2772, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Please help me to decode my messages.

Comment: `lsb.hide` expects the message to be a string. You have a tuple and you need to convert that to a string. For example for `p_coefficients = 123` and `seed = abc`, you could create the string `"123,abc"` and hide that. When you extract it, split it and reconstruct `p_coefficients` and `seed` again.

Comment: @Reti43 I used the string and that worked but I got another error. I used ```lsb.reveal(secret)```but that shows error as ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' ````.  How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have errors on both of these lines:

```
secret = secret.save("new.png")
clear_message = lsb.reveal(secret)
```

Judging by the examples in the `stegano` library documentation, you should do:

```
secret.save("new.png")   # this doesn't return anything, so don't reassign secret
clear_message = lsb.reveal("new.png")   # this function expects a filename
```

This should handle your steganography issues, the only remaining challenge is getting the string representation of your 2-tuple back into two separate objects. in this situation, the `ast.literal_eval` function is probably a good way to transform the string representation back into Python objects.

```
import ast  # this should be a the top of the file, with your other imports

new_c = ast.literal_eval(clear_message)  # parse the string into a tuple
new_a, new_b = new_c                     # unpack the tuple
```

Note that `ast.literal_eval` can only parse the simplest kinds of objects, the ones that have literal forms in Python code (tuples, lists, dictionaries, numbers, strings, etc.). If you need to encode something else that's more complicated, you'll need to write your own logic to handle its serialization and unserialization (with the steganography using the serialized string in the middle).